# exception when debugging opencart 3

Tags: php, twig, composer-php, opencart-3

I'm trying to debug an opencart 3 app with a theme built on it using twig.
When the app starts, the `twig/Autoloader.php` throws an exception:

> The Twig_Autoloader class is deprecated since version 1.21 and will be removed in 2.0. Use Composer instead.

any ideas?

Comment: twig_Autoloader class is deprecated since version 1.21 Use Composer instead.  nice error tough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated Twig_Autoloader problem has been around in OpenCart for a while now.

But it's just a warning and shouldn't stop you from using Translate Mate, unless you have PHP set to strict mode.

When you load the Translate Mate page, you getting this from the error log right ?

See version 3.0.2 https://github.com/chrisrollins65/cr_translate_mate/issues/18

Comment: the debugger was set to break at everything including warnings thank you for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already a post, but I came across the same problem. In my case this was resolved by installing PHP dependencies, such as:

```
apt-get install php-pear php7.4-curl php7.4-dev php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-zip php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml
```